# Save large size file (> 25 GB ) using JavaScript in indexedDB

Tags: javascript, jquery, indexeddb, large-files

I tried to save large file in indexedDB but my chrome is stopped responding when i use files larger than 500MB. My goal is to store 100GB file in indexedDB and also retrieve it back and download the same file.

So basically i need to use indexedDB as Large File Storage.

Please help me to achieve this.

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the section titled "Help others reproduce the problem".

Comment: How is it possible to have 100GB to store in a browser?

Comment: this guy just solved the problem : https://github.com/jimmywarting/StreamSaver.js

Comment: @AlaaKaddour the link is misleading the answer to implement it in Server rather than in Browser / Client side. Where technically it is not possible due to limitation on the browser itself.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like the limit of the IndexedDB don't allow you to store that amount of data.

If you read through the [storage limits](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Browser_storage_limits_and_eviction_criteria) it seems the maximum amount of data that can be stored would be 2 GB.

Quoted here would be the following:

> There's also another limit called group limit — this is defined as 20% of the global limit, but it has a minimum of 10 MB and a maximum of 2 GB. Each origin is part of a group (group of origins). There's one group for each eTLD+1 domain. For example:
>
> - mozilla.org — group1, origin1
> - [www.mozilla.org](http://www.mozilla.org) — group1, origin2
> - joe.blogs.mozilla.org — group1, origin3
> - firefox.com — group2, origin4

Chrome seems to use other limits, from which you can find more information [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/refs/heads/master/storage/browser/quota/quota_settings.cc#68)

Quoted with the following information

> Prior to M66, this was 10% of total storage instead of a fixed value on
> all devices. Now the minimum of a fixed value (2GB) and 10% is used to
> limit the reserve on devices with plenty of storage, but scale down for
> devices with extremely limited storage.

Answer (score 0):

There are limits on the size of the IndexedDB database. It will be calculated based on your available free capacity and the browser your are using, because some browsers use a slightly different metric.

On your case, indexedDB is given memory from the 'TEMPORARY' storage in Google Chrome. The temporary storage on Chrome has a default quota of 50% of the available disk space, 20% of which is available to your offline app. Requesting more quota against temporary storage doesn’t do anything.

Cheers.

```
Sources of information
[Stackoverflow][1]
[Mozila][2]
```